# Fluent NHibernate - mapping a CultureInfo object?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate

I have a class like so:

```
public class User
{
    public CultureInfo Culture {get;set;}
}
```

I have my mapping class like so:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        ??
    }
}
```

I would like to persist this users culture info to and from the database as the culture string (such as "en-US").  I'm a rookie when it comes to NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate.  How do I tell the mapper to use the culture string when persisting and to create the culture object when retrieving?

Answer (score 5):

It's not as easy as telling NHibernate to save the class as a string, you have to provide the mapping that works the other way too. To do that, implement `IUserType` as described in [this article](http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx).

You can then map it as `Map(x => x.Culture).CustomType<CultureType>()`, assuming your `IUserType` implementation is called `CultureType`.